# How to drag elements inside a Stack using Draggable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, draggable, flutter-animation

I have the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PScreenState createState() => _PScreenState();
}

class _PScreenState extends State<PScreen> {
  double width = 70.0, height = 70.0;
  double _x = 0;
  double _y = 0;

  AppBar appBar;

  Widget circle() {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Drag",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget draggable() {
    return Positioned(
      left: _x,
      top: _y,
      child:  Draggable(
          child: circle(),
          feedback: circle(),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
            setState(
              () {
                _x = dragDetails.offset.dx;
                // We need to remove offsets like app/status bar from Y
                _y = dragDetails.offset.dy -
                    appBar.preferredSize.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Drag'),
      leading: BackButton(onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, false);
      }),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          draggable(),
          circle(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this code, I can drag a circle on the screen and when I put it, the circle stays in the position I left, that's what I want to do. My problem is that I need to draw other things on the screen, like to draw another circle. When I put other elements within the Stack I can't drag my draggable circle anymore. If you remove "circle()" inside the Stack, the code will work, but with other elements inside the Stack it isn't working.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the second circle on top of the first one, that is why it is not working. Instead, wrap it with a position widget and align the second circle correctly so that you can interact with the first one without any problem.

```
  Positioned(
        left:0.0,
        bottom:0.0,
        child: circle()),
```

So, your complete code will look like

```
 class PScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PScreenState createState() => _PScreenState();
}

class _PScreenState extends State<PScreen> {
  double width = 70.0, height = 70.0;
  double _x = 0;
  double _y = 0;

  AppBar appBar;

  Widget circle() {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Drag",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget draggable() {
    return Positioned(
      left: _x,
      top: _y,
      child:  Draggable(
          child: circle(),
          feedback: circle(),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
            setState(
              () {
                _x = dragDetails.offset.dx;
                // We need to remove offsets like app/status bar from Y
                _y = dragDetails.offset.dy -
                    appBar.preferredSize.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Drag'),
      leading: BackButton(onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, false);
      }),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          draggable(),
          Positioned(
            left:0.0,
            bottom:0.0,
            child: circle()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```